# Trying to use cheese

Tags: 22.04, webcam, cheese

```
:~$ sudo cheese

(cheese:8523): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 00:36:30.321: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8523): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 00:36:30.321: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8523): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 00:36:30.461: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8523): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 00:36:30.463: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:8523): cheese-WARNING **: 00:36:30.890: Failed to decode JPEG image: ../ext/jpeg/gstjpegdec.c(1557): gst_jpeg_dec_handle_frame (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstDecodeBin:decodebin1/GstJpegDec:jpegdec1:
Decode error #55: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x10 0x10
```

The environment that I am using is VMWare Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I have also connected the camera from Player -> Removable Devices -> IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
The webcam is also being detected but I am not sure why it doesn't work

```
$lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 13d3:56eb IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. Virtual Bluetooth Adapter

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: GLib errors and warnings can be ignored, unless you are a developer.

Comment: Why are you using sudo?

Comment: @Jos I am trying to use the camera for object detection but the camera doesn't work

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can omit sudo. By doing so the GLib  warnings don't show up and only the error shows up. I was using sudo just to escalate privilege.